# Where does Blue Exorcist anime cut off in the manga?

Tags: blue-exorcist

I have finished *Blue Exorcist* and now I want to read the manga.

Where does the anime cut off in the manga?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=40870),

> Season 1 ended at **Vol. 4 Chapter 14** with an alternate ending and Season 2 at **Vol. 9 Chapter 34**.